# How to correctly forward atomic property from inner class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, atomic

Given class A with atomic properties from one of standard frameworks with header that looks like this:

```
@interface A : NSObject

@property float value;

@end
```

Class B extends, overrides and in some cases forward logic of class A with composition. Will value property in class B also atomic with this implementations?

```
@interface B : NSObject

@property float value;

@end

@implementation {
    A _innerA;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _innerA = [A new];
    }
    return self
}

- (float)value {
    return _innerA.value;
}

- (void)setValue:(float)value
{
    _innerA.value = value;
}

@end
```

Or should there be additional lock mechanism?

```
@implementation {
    A _innerA;
    dispatch_semaphore_t _valueSemaphore;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         _innerA = [A new];
         _valueSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    }
    return self
}

- (float)value {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_valueSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    float value = _innerA.value;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_valueSemaphore);
    return value;
}

- (void)setValue:(float)value
{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_valueSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    _innerA.value = value;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_valueSemaphore);
}
```

What if inner class itself will be defined as atomic property?

```
@interface B ()

@property A innerA;

@end

@implementation

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _innerA = [A new];
    }
    return self
}

- (float)value {
    return self.innerA.value;
}

- (void)setValue:(float)value
{
    self.innerA.value = value;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will value property in class B also atomic with this implementations?

In the sense you probably mean, yes.

Atomicity is a feature of the synthesised setter & getter of a property and effects accesses on the property's (usually automatically allocated) backing variable.

Only your property in `A` is synthesised and has a backing variable, and hence is "atomic". Your property in `B` is implemented by you with two methods and has no backing variable. When your setter & getter in `B` invoke the setter & getter in `A` then the latter behave as they always would, that is atomically.

That is the property in `A` is the sole determinant of whether access to its backing variable is atomic provided such accesses are always made via its setter & getter. If you bypass the setter & getter and access the backing variable directly then you bypass any atomicity provided by those accessors.

HTH